# Python throws SyntaxError on this code

Tags: python, dictionary

```
while 1:
    dic = {} #empty dictionary which will be used for storing all the data
    dic[raw_input("Enter the value you want to store: ")]  = input("Enter the access key of a value: ")
    ans = raw_input("Exit:e ; Store another variable : s; Acces a variable: a")
    if ans=="e":
        break; #exit the main loop
    elif ans == "s":
        continue;
    elif ans=="a":
        pass;
```

Please help

Comment: **Where** does it throw the syntax error? What is the full copy of the error message? What Python version? I cannot reproduce the error on Python 2.7.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I've been ignoring those for now as they are not the cause of the syntax error.

Comment: sorry guys by imstake

Comment: There is no syntax error on this code as it passes my interpreter just fine. So if there is an error somewhere else - it's outside of this code

Comment: @KanhaPrasad Please take some time and effort to explain your problems properly before you post, then repost a question

Answer (score 4):

You are using `input()` instead of `raw_input()`; this interprets the input as a Python expression. It is easy to make that throw a SyntaxError exception:

```
>>> input("Enter a sentence: ")
Enter a sentence: The Quick Brown Fox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    The Quick Brown Fox
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Use `raw_input()` throughout instead:

```
dic[raw_input("Enter the value you want to store: ")]  = raw_input("Enter the access key of a value: ")
```

You probably want to turn these two questions around:

```
dic[raw_input("Enter the access key of a value: ")] = raw_input("Enter the value you want to store: ")
```

Python will ask for the value *first*. If you need to ask for the key first, store it in a separate variable first:

```
key = raw_input("Enter the access key of a value: ")
dic[key] = raw_input("Enter the value you want to store: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You had your lines the wrong way around, you need:

```
dic[raw_input("Enter the access key of a value: ")]  =  input("Enter the value you want to store: ")
```

Not

```
 dic[raw_input("Enter the value you want to store: ")]  = input("Enter the access key of a value: ")
```

So complete code would be:

```
while 1:
    dic = {} #empty dictionary which will be used for storing all the data
    dic[raw_input("Enter the access key of a value: ")]  =  input("Enter the value you want to store: ")
    ans = raw_input("Exit:e ; Store another variable : s; Acces a variable: a")
    if ans=="e":
        break; #exit the main loop
    elif ans == "s":
        continue;
    elif ans=="a":
        pass;
```

Comment: That is not the cause of the syntax error though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can run that perfectly fine though

Comment: Exactly. That's what my answer addresses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The **reason** it produced a syntax error was because the prompt was misleading, resulting in the user typing in something which wasn't valid in the *actual* context. The use of input/raw_input is irrelevent to that. Afterwards you would need to `ast.liter_eval` the second inputted string anyway...

Comment: You cannot produce a `SyntaxError` with the `raw_input()` prompt.

Comment: Basically i have to make a program in which the user stores a certain value(a string) and has to give a key...I then give the user to either exit, save another value or access a previously stored key. Can someone give me clues on how to write this type of program

Comment: @MartijnPieters where did you learn python from?