# Input a Unix directory address in Python and not triggering str error

Tags: python, string, unix

I was trying to write a Python 2.7 script that processes a Unix directory input and use the input as a parameter to start another program.

However, I run into a problem that python's str() function doesn't like slashes in the input. When I am trying to str() a input with slashes, just like:

```
inputData = str(input('Put directory here:')) // OS is Mac OS X

> Put directory here: /User/username/abc.file
...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think this is due to str() cannot naturally process a string with slashes, because if I manually add quotes on each site during the input (keyboard input "/User/username/abc.file"), this error will not be triggered.

As this script needs to process user input, I hope it can add quotes automatically. I tried the following walk-around:

```
inputDataRaw = input('Put directory here:')
if (not inputDataRaw.startswith('"')) and (not inputDataRaw.startswith("'")):
    inputDataRaw = '"' + inputDataRaw
if (not inputDataRaw.endswith("'")) and (not inputDataRaw.endswith('"')):
    inputDataRaw = inputDataRaw + '"'
inputData = str(inputDataRaw)
```

But apparently the input value cannot be stored in inputDataRaw without str()ing it, and the first line directly triggered the same error. It looks like all functions that escape a slash in python can't work without forming a string first.

Would anyone please point out the correct way to walk-around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python throws SyntaxError on this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670872/python-throws-syntaxerror-on-this-code)

Comment: Which Python version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` attempts to `eval` the given input. That is, it's expecting something that would be a valid Python literal - including quotes for a string value. Use `raw_input` instead - that always returns the string the user entered, leaving conversions to your code.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> ```
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
> ```
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

Comment: I think I mixed up Python2.7 and Python3, the problem is solved, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, Python 3's `input` function has the behavior described for 2.x's `raw_input` function. Automatic `eval`'ing of user input was a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using python comments ;-)

Change:

```
inputData = str(input('Put directory here:')) // OS is Mac OS X
```

to:

```
inputData = str(input('Put directory here:')) # OS is Mac OS X
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Sometimes most obvious thing is hardest to spot. It seems too obvious ;-)

Comment: TBH this comment was added solely for explaining the problem here, not in the original code. Looks like I wrote too much PHP these days. Peter DeGlopper's solution is right. However, still thank you for spotting this　:D